# NoMethodError: undefined method - How to find a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm getting the following error:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `find_it' for #<struct xJob xxxx_id=527>>
```

I have a controller, which creates a delayed_job as follows, at the end of the controller method:

```
xJob.new(@xxxx.id).perform
```

Then in /lib/xJob.rb:

```
class xJob < Struct.new(:xxxx_id)

  include ActionView::Helpers

  def perform

    begin
     .......
     goodstuff  =  find_it(stuff)
     .......
    rescue Exception => e
     .....
    end
  end

  def self.find_it(body)
    ....
  end

end
```

I needed to add the self to self.find_it otherwise it I couldn't test that method in rspec. But now it seems to be breaking outside of RSPEC.

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the "self" from the find_it method declaration. Because its when you define it like that it becomes a class method of xJob, instead of a instance method.

Comment: Thanks but then in my rspec I have:     xxxx = :: xJob::find_it(stuff) and if I remove the self. then that fails. So what do I do?

Comment: RSPEC then fails with NoMethodError:
       undefined method

Comment: then just use, goodstuff = xJob.find_it(stuff) , instead of just "goodstuff = find_it(stuff)"

Comment: @Rishav, thanks I've tried that with the following in RSPEC: goodstuff = :: xJob. find_it(stuff) but that errors with NoMethodError:
       undefined method `find_it' for xJob:Class

Comment: I should add that find_it is inside a lib, that I use with delayed job, that looks like this: class xJob < Struct.new(:xxxx_id)

Comment: Should this perhaps be a helper? and not here?